# Error in number of bindings supplied and values supplied

Tags: python, sqlite, win32com

I am trying to convert an excel sheet into an sqlite3 db using win32com module in python. My excel sheet has 6 columns and so my a part of my python code is:

```
for row in exceldata:
      c.execute('INSERT INTO exceltable1 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',row)
conn.commit()
```

But python gives me the following error:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO exceltable VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',row)
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 5 supplied.
```

If I try to remove one question mark and run it again, the error now becomes:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO exceltable1 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',row)
OperationalError: table exceltable1 has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied
```

Could anyone please explain to me whats happening here and if there is any solution...
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure what the value of `row` is, and how many items it has:

```
 print row, len(row)
```

Then try and use the complete insert sql statement:

```
 insert into table (col1, col2, col3, ...) values (?, ?,? ...)
```

and see what happens. This should solve your problem, or at least let you understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling it that you have 6 columns (arguments), but you're only giving it 1 arguments. This is why it's telling you that you're missing 5 column.